# Sharepoint getListItems beyond capacity

Tags: list, search, web-services

I am using the Sharepoint Search web service and along with the results that I retrieve, I also want them to return the ObjectId, title, ows_UniqueId, ows_name, ows_filepath etc etc. 
Currently upon conducting a search , it only retrieves the title, author, and the LinkUrl for whatever has been searched.

I need to invoke the Webs web services that has the method getObjectIDFromURL using the above LinkUrls. The returned ObjectId XML tag has a ListID(GUID) attribute which I extract and then finally invoke the Lists Web Service's getListItems method that accepts a ListID(GUID) to retrieve the List Item.

The z:row XML Element has attributes (ows_uniqueId, ows_name, ows_createdOn, ows_modifiedOn and ows_name) all of which are of interest to me.

Is there anyway that this can be retrieved in a single way, perhaps using the Search web services Query methods and by specifying these as managed properties. I have been seeking online for a list of acceptable managed properties but haven't gotten any luck with it.

Looking forward to suggestions.